# async.applyEachSeries converted to highland.js

Tags: async.js, highland.js

I have this snippet working fine using `async.applyEachSeries`.

```
var async = require("async");

function firstThing(state, next) {
  state.firstThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(next);
}

function secondThing(state, next) {
  state.secondThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(next);
}

var state = {};
async.applyEachSeries([
  firstThing,
  secondThing
], state, function (error) {
  console.log(error, state);
});
```

I have made several attempts to convert it to highland.js but I'm not grokking the plumbing there. I'm pretty sure I need to do `_.wrapCallback(firstThing)` for both firstThing and secondThing but not sure whether I need `_.pipeline` or `.series()` or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a nice 1:1 translation at the moment, since Highland lacks an 'applyEach', but by changing (or wrapping) the firstThing and lastThing functions you might get a nice enough result:

```
var _ = require('highland');

/**
 * These functions now return the state object,
 * and are wrapped with _.wrapCallback
 */

var firstThing = _.wrapCallback(function (state, next) {
  state.firstThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(function () {
    next(null, state);
  });
});

var secondThing = _.wrapCallback(function (state, next) {
  state.secondThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(function () {
    next(null, state);
  });
});

var state = {};

_([state])
  .flatMap(firstThing)
  .flatMap(secondThing)
  .apply(function (state) {
    // updated state
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my own attempts to abandon async for Highland, I've come to use `.map(_.wrapCallback).invoke('call')` with some regularity. We can use it here:

```
var _ = require('highland');

var state = {};

function firstThing(state, next) {
  state.firstThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(next);
}

function secondThing(state, next) {
  state.secondThingDone = true;
  setImmediate(next);
}

_([firstThing, secondThing])
  .map(_.wrapCallback)
  .invoke('call', [null, state])
  .series().toArray(function() {
    console.log(state)
  });
```

This lets us keep your functions as they were, it expands nicely to more than two 'things', and I think it feels more like a direct breakdown of applyEachSeries.

If we need to bind `this` or pass different arguments to each function, we can just use `.bind` when constructing the stream and omit the `call` arguments:

```
_([firstThing.bind(firstThing, state),
  secondThing.bind(secondThing, state)])
  .map(_.wrapCallback)
  .invoke('call')
  .series().toArray(function() {
    console.log(state)
  });
```

On the other hand, this approach is more side-effecty; the stuff in our stream is no longer what we're ultimately transforming and making use of.

Finally, having to use `.toArray` at the end feels odd, although maybe that's just an argument for adding `.done(cb)` to Highland.